# What is a suitable method to use when sending info using PHP?

Tags: php

I've made myself an HTML input

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
```

and tried to print out the value that I typed using PHP.

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>
```

but it only prints some simple strings. When I entered: '<\?\p\h\p\?>' into the input form it just doesn't do anything at all. I want the form to handle all type of strings and print out exactly what has been input. How can you fix this mistake? Is there a suitable PHP method to achieve this task.

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code!

Comment: PHP is as complex or simple as you need it and, with no offence, you are at the *very* start of the beginning. You need to read some tutorials from other places on the internet rather than ask very basic questions like that here. Read about PHP and HTML forms, and also once you have a grasp on those, make sure to read about PHP and HTML form *security*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your output string:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name']); ?>
```

So, the `<` symbol will be transformed to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

Comment: @James Maybe, put it into comment?

Comment: @Alvarez Please, accept the answer, so the question could be closed.